# Did the author regard this as a single concept?

Tags: grammar, usage

In the following passage, why did the author use ***contributes***, not ***contribute***? Is the subject of the sentence ***the corresponding lack of social and relaxation time***? Or, did the author regard ***this extra stress, and the corresponding lack of social and relaxation time*** as a single concept?

> Once we recognize the false­cause issue, we see it everywhere. For
> example, a recent long­term study of University of Toronto medical
> students concluded that medical school class presidents lived an
> average of 2.4 years less than other medical school graduates. At
> first glance, this seemed to imply that being a medical school class
> president is bad for you. Does this mean that you should avoid being
> medical school class president at all costs? Probably not. Just
> because being class president is correlated with shorter life
> expectancy does not mean that it causes shorter life expectancy. In
> fact, it seems likely that the sort of person who becomes medical
> school class president is, on average, extremely hard­working,
> serious, and ambitious. Perhaps this extra stress, and the
> corresponding lack of social and relaxation time―rather than being
> class president per se―***contributes*** to lower life expectancy. If
> so, the real lesson of the study is that we should all relax a little
> and not let our work take over our lives.

[Struck By Lightning: The Curious World Of Probabilities](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=QDsiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT82&lpg=PT82&dq=Perhaps%20this%20extra%20stress,%20and%20the%20corresponding%20lack%20of%20social%20and%20relaxation%20time%E2%80%95rather%20than%20being%20class%20president%20per%20se%E2%80%95&source=bl&ots=I9OhHbTN9a&sig=ACfU3U0t1xnbKuIrB5FgpsV6j_zeyOBhyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio1vyIjbP1AhUEPnAKHWf4CIcQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=Perhaps%20this%20extra%20stress%2C%20and%20the%20corresponding%20lack%20of%20social%20and%20relaxation%20time%E2%80%95rather%20than%20being%20class%20president%20per%20se%E2%80%95&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a single concept. You could even put the second noun phrase in parentheses, as an explanation of *extra stress*:

> ... this extra stress (and the corresponding lack of social and relaxation time)―rather than being class president per se―contributes...